# How can I use keyword 'this' in jQuery ajax success handle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class like this :

```
var MyClass = function(){  
    this.field = 'field';  
}  
MyClass.prototype.doSth(data){  
    //doSth with data and this.field;   
}  
MyClass.prototype.getData(){  
    $.ajax({  
        type: "post",  
        url: 'myurl',  
    }).success(this.doSth);  
}
```

but in doSth all 'this' point to the jquery ajax object not MyClass instance.

I added a static filed `_self` to point `MyClass` self `MyClass._self = this;` then change all the `this` to `MyClass._self` in doSth can fix. But I think this is ugly.

I want to know is there any way to solve my problem with out modify doSth body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an object using the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) parameter to be used int he callbacks.

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "post",  
    url: 'myurl',
    context: this
}).success(function(d){
  this.doSth(d);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
MyClass.prototype.getData = function(){  
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({  
        type: "post",  
        url: 'myurl',  
    }).success(function(){
        self.doSth();
    });  
};
```

The definition of "getData" needs to a function as shown here - your version didn't make a lot of sense.

Or you could even use jQuery.proxy (See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/ )

```
MyClass.prototype.getData = function(){  
    $.ajax({  
        type: "post",  
        url: 'myurl',  
    }).success( $.proxy(this.doSth, this) );  
};
```

$.proxy creates a wrapper function which will call the enclosed function in the context of the given object.